# Loading assets on click

Tags: aframe

I'm referencing this post: [How can I add a loading effect before all assets are loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39586429/how-can-i-add-a-loading-effect-before-all-assets-are-loaded)

I have a click event for the user to enter the experience, and I want to ensure all assets are loaded when the user clicks.

I have this code, but the "OK LOADED" never appears in the console:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('loadscene', {
  init: function () {
  this.el.addEventListener("click", (e)=> {
  document.querySelector('a-assets').addEventListener('loaded', function () {console.log("OK LOADED");
    });
    document.getElementById('sts-live').setAttribute('visible', true);
    });
  }
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assets try to load before any of the components or scene run. Simply just have a component toggle the visibility, such as on `play`. Removing the event listener should work in your example.

The double event listener is weird in JS in general. That says you want to wait for the click, and only after the click then wait for the assets...they can be separated.

Comment: I have some sounds that are activated by mouseenter on some objects. Sometimes they play, and sometimes I get a message:  components:sound:warn Sound not loaded yet. It will be played once it finished loading.  But if I'm understanding you correctly, the assets should all be loaded. So what could be happening here?